# No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' - But with Numpy, Numba

Tags: python, numpy, pip, numba

I was trying to run

```py
import numpy as np
```

However, it kept returning an error:

```
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

So I tried to follow instructions...

```bash
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

But this just kept on returning another error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
numba 0.57.1 requires numpy<1.25,>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.26.2 which is incompatible.
```

So I tried

```
pip install numba --upgrade
```

But this downgraded Numpy to 1.24.4 again...

And I am stuck in this loop. How do I solve this?

My Version is Python 3.11

Comment: What about specifying an explicit version? For example, numpy==1.26.2 numba==0.58.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try `pip install --upgrade numpy numba`. It should work.